# ASP.NET CultureInfo change it on one page make it global

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

How do I change the language CultureInfo from a dropdownlist and from there make it global. I have set up a Countries List in a dropdownlist with the regioninfo TwoLetterISORegionName what do i need to do to too make it global from the selected item in the dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the [System.Globalization.CultureInfo MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx)

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ChangeCultures.aspx) also has a demo.